# Chaining multiple publishers transforming the responses

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, chaining

I want to chain one mono after each flux event. The mono publisher will need information from each event published by the flux. The response should be a flux with data of the flux event and the mono response.

After digging, I end up with a map inside a flatMap. The code looks like this:

```
override fun searchPets(petSearch: PetSearch): Flux<Pet> {
    return petRepository
        .searchPets(petSearch) // returns Flux<pet>
        .flatMap { pet -> 
            petService
            .getCollarForMyPet() // returns Mono<collar>
            .map { collar -> PetConverter.addCollarToPet(pet, collar) } //returns pet (now with with collar)
        }
}
```

My main concerns are:

- Is a code smell using a map inside a flatMap?
- Will pet variable content suffer race conditions with multiple flux events coming, and also the mono events?
- Is there any better way to approach this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is perfectly fine.

The Reactive Streams specification mandates that `onNext` events don't overlap, so there won't be an issue with race conditions.

`flatMap` introduces concurrency though, so multiple calls to the `PetService` will run in parallel. This shouldn't be an issue, unless `searchPets` emits some instance of `Pet` twice.

Not that due to that concurrency, `flatMap` can kind of reorder pets in this scenario. Imagine the search returns `petA` then `petB`, but the `petService` call for `petA` takes longer. In the ouptut of the flatMap, `petB` would be emitted first (with its collar set), then `petA`.